# A question on closed subgroups of $U(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups

What are all the closed connected subgroups of $U(2)$? The trivial ones are $S^1$, $S^1\times S^1$ and $SU(2)$. Are there others?

Also, which ones have an invariant function that is linear? Clearly there is no such function for the subgroup $S^1\times S^1$. But for instance if the $S^1$ acts only on the first factor of $(z_1,z_2)$, then $z_2$ is an invariant linear function for the action.

Comment: Have you considered finite subgroups of $U(2)$?

Comment: They have to be connected, so the only finite subgroup is identity isn't it?

Comment: @Poincare-Lelong Right.

Comment: Yes, sorry, overlooked the "connected" requirement.

Comment: If you mean "up to an isomorphism", then you have the complete list (plus the trivial subgroup and $U(2)$ itself). If you mean "up to conjugation", there are different $S^1$'s. In any case, all $S^1$'s have nonzero invariant linear functions and none of the other subgroups do.

Comment: @ Moishe Cohen Thanks!

Comment: @Moishe Cohen A question on the last part of your comment. What if the S^1 acts as $\theta\cdot (z_1,z_2) = (e^{i\lambda_1\theta_1}z_1,e^{i\lambda_2\theta_2}z_1) $?. Does it have invariant linear functions if neither $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ is zero? For instance for the action $\theta\cdot (z_1,z_2) = (e^{i\theta}z_1,e^{i\theta}z_2)$, are there any invariant linear functions?

Comment: @Poincare-Lelong: No, it does not have any invariant linear functions (unless $\theta=2\pi n$ of course); it is a good exercise to work this out.